# How to keep richtextbox text sent format while adding a new font style and color without changing all the previous text

Tags: c#

i have a richtextbox to send text to another richtextbox but when i change the font for a new text it changes all the previous text how would i keep the previous format and send the new font and color?

{
public partial class Form6 : Form
{
private int totalSeconds;
private ColorDialog colorDialog;
private FontDialog fd = new FontDialog();
public Form6()
{
InitializeComponent();
}
Color _color = Color.Blue;
bool _first = true;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form7 f7 = new Form7();
f7.ShowDialog();
}

```
    private void button25_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form8 f8 = new Form8();
        f8.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void button18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            this.richTextBox2.Font = fd.Font;
            
        }
    }

    private void button17_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            this.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;            
        }
    }

    private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        colorDialog = new ColorDialog();
        this.button33.Enabled = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            this.comboBox2.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            this.comboBox3.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
        this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 15;
        this.comboBox3.SelectedIndex = 59;
    }


    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox2.SelectionColor = _color;
        if (_first)              
            richTextBox2.SelectedText = richTextBox4.Text;
        else
            richTextBox2.SelectedText = Environment.NewLine + richTextBox4.Text;
        richTextBox4.Clear();
        richTextBox4.Focus();
        richTextBox4.ResetText();
        richTextBox4.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button16_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button19_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button17_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            richTextBox4.ForeColor = colorDialog1.Color;
            _color = colorDialog1.Color;
            button17.BackColor = colorDialog1.Color;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (totalSeconds > 0)
        {
            totalSeconds--;
            int minutes = totalSeconds / 60;
            int seconds = totalSeconds - (minutes * 60);
            this.label3.Text = minutes.ToString() + ":" + seconds.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            this.timer1.Stop();
        }
    }

    private void button32_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button32.Enabled = false;
        this.button33.Enabled = true;

        int minutes = int.Parse(this.comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        int seconds = int.Parse(this.comboBox3.SelectedItem.ToString());

        totalSeconds = (minutes * 60) + seconds;

        this.timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void button33_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button33.Enabled = false;
        this.button32.Enabled = true;

        totalSeconds = 0;
        this.timer1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: This question needs a lot of improvement. The explanation of the problem is inadequate, the code is poorly formatted, names like `Form8` and `button25` give zero indication of what anything is for and it's very hard to believe that all that code is relevant to the problem. You should spend a significant amount of time in the Help Center to learn how to ask a question properly. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I second jmcilhinney's comment. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And then create a form with the minimum amount of code necessary to reproduce the specific problem you're trying to solve. Your question is more likely to be noticed by someone who can answer it if you tag it with the UI framework that you're using - I guess it's Windows Forms, if so then use the tag [winforms].